# 2nd if-condition in for-loop does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have an array `data` which contains objects which look like that:

```
data = [{
    "array": "arr_id_0",
    "direct": "+",
    "axis": "x",
    "s": "1"
  },
  {
    "array": "arr_id_1",
    "direct": "+",
    "axis": "y",
    "s": "2"
  },
  {
    "array": "arr_id_2",
    "direct": "+",
    "axis": "z",
    "s": "3"
  },
  {
    "array": "arr_id_3",
    "direct": "+",
    "axis": "x",
    "s": "4"
  }
]
```

The `axis` can be altered to `x`, `y`, `z`. Depending on `axis` i need to write the value of `s` into the corresponding array `sum_x`, `sum_y` or `sum_z`. At the end I need the sum of each array.

I wrote the following code using the for-loop to iterate through `data` , choose the s value and write it into on of the `sum`-arrays.

```
function sum_axis() {
  var sum_x = [];
  var sum_y = [];
  var sum_z = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'x') {
      sum_x.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])
    };
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'y') {
      sum_y.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])
    };
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'z') {
      sum_z.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])
    };
    console.log(data)
    console.log(sum_x, sum_y, sum_z)
  }
}
```

The **problem** is that the values are all being written into `sum_x`. Everything else seems to work just fine. So the 2nd condition is not being touched (at least it seems like that). I can't figure out why it is not working. I am sure it is something simple but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have tried

```
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'x') sum_x.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'y') sum_y.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'z') sum_z.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])

    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'x') {sum_x.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])}
    else if (data[i]['axis'] == 'y') {sum_y.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])}
    else if (data[i]['axis'] == 'z') {sum_z.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])}

    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'x') sum_x.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s']);
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'y') sum_y.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s']);
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'z') sum_z.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s']);
```

expected output is:

```
sum_x = [1,4]
sum_y = [2]
sum_z = [3]
```

actual output is:

```
sum_x = [1,2,3,4]
sum_y = []
sum_z = []
```

Comment: i suggest you give a orgin array,and give an expected output?that is more clear than your words and codes

Comment: I understand. I just did update it. I hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: Your code is working correctly.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue. Are you sure your comparison is with double `==`? Are you sure you did not by accident write `sum_x.splice` three times instead of `sum_y` and `sum_z`? Please provide code that when executed shows the result as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, the confusion is probably because you have the last `console.log` inside of the loop, if you take it out the loop then you'll get the result you want.

```js
var data = [{
    "array": "arr_id_0",
    "direct": "+",
    "axis": "x",
    "s": "1"
  },
  {
    "array": "arr_id_1",
    "direct": "+",
    "axis": "y",
    "s": "2"
  },
  {
    "array": "arr_id_2",
    "direct": "+",
    "axis": "z",
    "s": "3"
  },
  {
    "array": "arr_id_3",
    "direct": "+",
    "axis": "x",
    "s": "4"
  }
];

function sum_axis() {
  var sum_x = [];
  var sum_y = [];
  var sum_z = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'x') {
      sum_x.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])
    };
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'y') {
      sum_y.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])
    };
    if (data[i]['axis'] == 'z') {
      sum_z.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])
    };
    //console.log(data)
  }
  console.log(sum_x, sum_y, sum_z); // [ '1', '4' ] [ '2' ] [ '3' ]
}

sum_axis(data);
```

Comment: The problem was that the `axis`-value was not passed on to the array coreectly. So basically it was writing `x` in the `axis` location. I have fixed it now. But thanks for the `console.log` tip. That actually made me realise the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is okay. Try running this in your console

```js
var data = [{"array":"arr_id_0","direct":"+","axis":"x","s":"1"}, 
        {"array":"arr_id_1","direct":"+","axis":"y","s":"2"},
        {"array":"arr_id_2","direct":"+","axis":"z","s":"3"},
        {"array":"arr_id_3","direct":"+","axis":"x","s":"4"}]
function sum_axis(){
var sum_x = [];
var sum_y = [];
var sum_z = [];
    for (var i=0 ; i<data.length; i++){
        if (data[i]['axis'] == 'x') {sum_x.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])};
        if (data[i]['axis'] == 'y') {sum_y.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])};
        if (data[i]['axis'] == 'z') {sum_z.splice(i, 1, data[i]['s'])};
        console.log(data)
        console.log(sum_x, sum_y, sum_z)
    } 
}
sum_axis()
```

I haven't changed anything. You maybe accessing the wrong data variable.

Comment: I kinda did. See my comment on the answer above.